How can I add liquidity for a token I want in a Raydium CPMM pool?
require('./globals');
const { Percent } = require('@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2');
const BN = require('bn.js');
const Decimal = require('decimal.js');
const { lpBotServices, raydiumServices } = require('./app/utils');
const { cpmmAddress } = require('./cpmmAddress');
async function cpmmAddLiquidity(poolId) {
try {
const owner = lpBotServices.readJsonFile('./secret.json');
    const raydium = await raydiumServices.initSDK(owner, true);
    const data = await raydium.cpmm.getPoolInfoFromRpc(poolId);

    const poolInfo = data.poolInfo;
    const poolKeys = data.poolKeys;

    console.warn('Pool Info:', poolInfo, 'Pool Keys:', poolKeys);

    const uiInputAmount = '1000';

    const inputAmount = new BN(
        new Decimal(uiInputAmount)
            .mul(10 ** poolInfo.mintB.decimals)
            .toFixed(0),
    );

    const slippage = new Percent(1, 100); // 1%
    const baseIn = true;

    const { execute } = await raydium.cpmm.addLiquidity({
        poolInfo,
        poolKeys,
        inputAmount,
        slippage,
        baseIn,
    });
    const { txId } = await execute();
    console.warn('pool deposited', { txId });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding liquidity to cpmm:', error);
    return;
}

}
cpmmAddLiquidity(cpmmAddress.cpmmPoolId);
I have this code and I have a CPMM pool ID with the token pair SOL/tokenA. I want to add liquidity for SOL, which I can do using the above code. However, I want to add liquidity for tokenA. How can I do this? If there are any mistakes in my understanding that we can't add liquidity for tokenA, please help me understand.
